# Как транслировать статическую картинку из файла через rtsp

Tags: python, rtsp

Есть монитор видеонаблюдения, на него (в сетку 3*3) выведено изображение с 8-ми камер.
Одна ячейка свободна.
Возникла идея отображать там произвольную картинку (например скриншот из личного кабинета провайдера с остатками чего-либо)
Для этого на сервере запускаем python-скрипт, который создаёт (не потребляет) rtsp поток на основе картинки их /tmp/tmp.jpg

Понимаю, что нужно использовать gst-launch-1.0, но как в качестве источника использовать единственный JPEG-файл?

Answer (score 0):

Чему уж вы будете транслировать - дело ваше, я бы, возможно, остановился на ffmpeg. Но вот сделать видео из одного файла можно с помощью OpenCV:

```
import cv2

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
video = cv2.VideoWriter("out.avi", fourcc, 1, (600, 480)) # размеры можете
# получить из размеры картинки (см. cv2.imread())

i=90   # можно обойтись и без цикла в 90 фреймов, просто записав фрейм один раз
       # я просто придал видео некоторую длину для наглядности.
while i:
    video.write(cv2.imread('sampleimage.png'))
    i-=1

video.release()
```

на выходе получите out.avi. ну а дальше транслируйте его бесконечным циклом.